# Laravel wildcard string search

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I did a query and got a collection of 11 arrays of db objects. Basically 11 posts. I need to do a wildcard search if a string is present inside any of these posts (in title or in model or description). How best to achieve it? I tried with multiple orWhere, but doesn't seem to be working.

My function

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'search' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
    ]);
    $search=$request->input('search');
    $posts = Country::where('country_name', $request->input('country'))->first()->posts;

    $customers=$posts::where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('model','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('notes','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
    ->get();

    dd($posts);
}
```

**$posts - response**

```
 Collection {#367 ▼
          #items: array:11 [▼
            0 => Post {#368 ▼
              #table: "posts"
              #dates: array:1 [▶]
              #fillable: array:18 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:22 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "title" => "Brand New Harley Davidson For Sale"
                "make_id" => "1"
                "model" => "Sportster"
                "year" => 2019
                "price" => "987890.00"
                "mileage" => 8798
                "mileage_unit" => "KM"
                "negotiable" => "negotiable"
                "condition" => "All Good"
                "plate" => null
                "vin" => null
                "color" => null
                "notes" => null
                "description" => null
                "created_by" => 1
                "status_change" => "2019-06-12 02:35:51"
                "status" => "Deleted"
                "slug" => "1560305498-Brand-New-Harley-Davidson-For-Sale"
                "created_at" => "2019-06-12 02:11:38"
                "updated_at" => "2019-06-12 02:36:50"
                "laravel_through_key" => "IND"
              ]
              #original: array:22 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            1 => Post {#369 ▶}
            2 => Post {#370 ▶}
            3 => Post {#371 ▶}
            4 => Post {#372 ▶}
            5 => Post {#373 ▶}
            6 => Post {#374 ▶}
            7 => Post {#375 ▶}
            8 => Post {#376 ▶}
            9 => Post {#377 ▶}
            10 => Post {#378 ▶}
          ]
        }
```

Comment: so you need to search with relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$posts` is referring to

```
$posts = Country::where('country_name', $request->input('country'))->first()->posts;
```

which is not including the search query, you should dump `$customers` to see the result.

Besides that, your `$customers` query is irrelevant with the `$posts` one, you are making two different queries. Your current `$posts` will return all countries' posts.

Try [**Query Relations**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

```
$posts = Country::where('country_name', $request->input('country'))->first()->posts()
    ->where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('model','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('notes','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query.

```
$posts = Country::with(['posts' => function($oQuery) use($search){ 
 $oQuery->where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('model','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('notes','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');}])->where('country_name', $request->input('country'))->first();
```